# c# Wpf binding to DbSet<T>.Local (EF CORE)

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, entity-framework-core, .net-6

в WPF приложении мне надо привязать `DataGrid` к коллекции `Local` из объекта `DbSet<T>` контекста `DbContext`. Microsoft советует делать через `Local.ToObservableCollection()`. Полученная через этот метод коллекция, остается синхронизированной с `Local` (множество отслеживаемых трекером сущностей).

**Проблема:** при асинхронном запросе к БД, который меняет Local, вылетает исключение: `Данный тип CollectionView не поддерживает изменения в своем SourceCollection из потока, отличного от потока Dispatcher.` Получается EF Core после выполненного запроса меняет Local в другом потоке(не UI). И выходит, что, привязавшись к Local, можно делать только синхронные запросы к БД?

Если иcпользовать `Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(...)`, то это по сути тоже синхронный запрос, который может вешать UI. Особенно, если БД недоступна, то всё зависает на 10 секунд и только потом вылезает исключение о недоступности БД. Что я делаю неправильно? Посоветуйте, пожалуйста.

Всё что я пока придумал - это проверять в диспетчере перед самим запросом доступность БД, чтобы хотя бы не виснуть на 10 секунд.

ссылка на тестовый пример с проблемой:
*https://github.com/OlegFj17/TestingBindingToLocal_EF_6*

Мои тестовая сущность и контекст:

```
public class Shop
    {
        public int ShopId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }

public DbSet<Shop> Shops { get; set; }
        public DbCtx()
        {            
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=AAA3;Trusted_Connection=True;");
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Shop>().HasData(new Shop[]{
                new Shop{ShopId=1, Name="Shop1", Address="AAA"},
                new Shop{ShopId=2, Name="Shop2", Address="BBB"},
                new Shop{ShopId=3, Name="Shop3", Address="CCC"},
                new Shop{ShopId=4, Name="Shop4", Address="DDD"},
                new Shop{ShopId=5, Name="Shop5", Address="EEE"}
            });
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

далее - codebehind (MVVM и прочее опускаем для простоты примера):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {  
        DbCtx Db { get; }

        private ObservableCollection<Shop>? shopsCollection = new();
        /// <summary>
        /// к этому свойству в XAML делается привязка 
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<Shop>? ShopsCollection
        {
            get => shopsCollection; 
            set 
            { 
                shopsCollection = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ShopsCollection));
            }
        }
        
        public MainWindow() 
        {
            Db = new DbCtx();

            //связываемся с коллекцией Local
            ShopsCollection = Db.Shops.Local.ToObservableCollection();            

            //закачиваем первую запись для наглядности, остальные кнопками
            Db.Shops.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Shop1");

            DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Sync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //закачиваем следующую запись, это изменяет Local-коллекцию
                //но в главном потоке, поэтому всё ок.
                Db.Shops.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Shop2");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{ex}");
            }
        }

        private async void Button_Async(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {               
                //закачиваем следующую запись асинхронно, это изменяет Local-коллекцию через другой поток
                //поэтому получаем исключение, что SourceCollection для ICollectionView (встроенная, из DataGrid)
                //не может быть изменен из потока отличного от главного(UI)
                await Db.Shops.LoadAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        private async void Button_Async_Dispatcher(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //имитируем какую-то дополнительную работу асинхронного метода
            await Task.Delay(3000).ConfigureAwait(false);
            try
            {
                //здесь по сути происходит синхронное обращение к БД из UI
                //если запрос большой, то UI виснет;
                //если отключить БД("нет соединения"), то UI виснет ровно на 10 секунд и только потом
                //выводит исключение, что БД не доступна
                await Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(
                    () => Db.Shops.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "Shop4"));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{ex.Message}");
            }
        }
        ...
        
    }
```

и привязка в XAML:

```
<Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="20">
            <Button Content="Sync Load" Width="100" Height="50"  Margin="10"
                Click="Button_Sync"/>
            <Button Content="Async Load with Exception" MinWidth="100" Height="50" Margin="10" Padding="5"
                Click="Button_Async"/>
            <Button Content="Async Load with Dispatcher" MinWidth="100" Height="50" Margin="10" Padding="5"
                Click="Button_Async_Dispatcher"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ShopsCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Width="500" Height="500"/>

    </Grid>
```

**Решение:** мне помог комментарий @John про EnableCollectionSynchronization. Ссылка по теме внизу

Comment: Весь прикол в асинхронном вызове. При синхронном вызове понятно, что UI поток читает и UI поток заполняет коллекцию элементом. А теперь подумайте, кто это самое чтение выполняет при асинхронном вызове? Если не UI поток, то очевидно, что это какой-то другой поток. И именно этот другой поток заполняет коллекцию новым элементом, а дальше внутренний код вызывает обновление UI, чтобы этот код добавить.

Comment: С EF честно говоря не работал, но в данном случае (если без всей это MVVM) вижу очевидный способ просто проксировать изменения в ObservableCollection, который создаёт EF, в ваш собственный экземпляр ObservableCollection, который вы присваиваете в ShopsCollection. Т.е. у EF подписываетесь на CollectionChanged и каждое изменение кидаете через Dispatcher в ваш ObservableCollection.

Comment: Ещё есть "магическая" фигня - EnableCollectionSynchronization (позволяет менять коллекцию из нескольких потоков), но имхо так себе штука, не люблю я такие неочевидные вещи... Лучше просто иметь ObservableCollection, который меняется только из UI (через Dispatcher) и всё.

Comment: Вся суть вопроса 1) Делаете `Local.ToObservableCollection()` 2) вяжете `DataGrid` к этой коллекции 3) делаете запрос в базу 4) ловите исключение, что, что была попытка изменить коллекцию из стороннего потока. Всё. Я вам в прошлый раз говорил, что остальную воду выкиньте, она только отвлекает от сути вопроса, а вы опять этот `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync()` непонятно зачем приплели к этой истории. Он во-первых совершенно бесполезен, во-вторых еще и глючит, или вам надо, чтобы кто-то еще вам это повторил? :) 2/3 кода можно было бы не писать.

Comment: @John здесь проблема не в синхронизации коллекции для многопоточки, а в вызове `OnCollectionChanged` или `OnPropertyChanged` из стороннего потока, добавление `EnableCollectionSynchronization` вообще ничего не решит. Мне известен ряд костылей, как это объехать наверняка, но я не знаю прямого решения, так как источник проблемы выглядит как глюк внутри EF. Если никто ничего не подскажет, я напишу костыль для автора.

Comment: @John 1) конечно, может, я был наивен, но Microsoft сама в документации предлагала из WPF привязываться к Local.ToObservableCollection(). Логично было подумать с моей стороны, что они могли как-то предусмотреть работу со своими асинхронными EF-запросами.

Comment: @John 2) если подписываться на CollectionChanged, то этим можно отследить добавление, удаление элементов (и этот способ действительно решает часть проблемы), но не их внутреннее изменение (например, если для отслеживаемой записи делаем Reload, то как узнать, когда такие изменения произошли? INPC для модели здесь не помогает) Но всё равно, спасибо большое за советы!

Comment: @aepot  Нет. Повторять мне не надо. Eсли написал, значит посчитал нужным. Люблю лаконичность. Но по опыту, на Stackoverflow она редко прокатывает. Все спешат. Конкретно про Dispatcher написал, потому что в 90% случаев, когда видят исключение: "Данный тип CollectionView не поддерживает изменения в своем SourceCollection из потока, отличного от потока Dispatcher" начинают сразу советовать Dispatcher.Invoke() - вот чтобы избежать и написал.

Comment: @aepot  Если вы знаете какой-то 100%-но работающий костыль, поделитесь, пожалуйста. Не стоит в себе всё это держать.. ) Я могу просто пообещать не отмечать его правильным ответом, пока не наступит время Х или вообще не отмечать -  как вам будет удобно. Спасибо!!!

Comment: @John очень жаль, что вы прорекламировали EnableCollectionSynchronization с многочисленными оговорками.. - я наполнился общим скепсисом этой ветки и не сразу решил заняться этим вопросом. А он мне как раз и помог. Когда разобрался с темой, использование EnableCollectionSynchronization мне показалось много удобнее и проще, чем  proxy.  Спасибо огромное! Не понимаю, как отметить ваш комментарий в качестве "правильного ответа"..

Comment: Ссылка для остальных на хороший текст по [**EnableCollectionSynchronization**](https://web.archive.org/web/20200813114730/http://10rem.net/blog/2012/01/20/wpf-45-cross-thread-collection-synchronization-redux)

Comment: @ОлегШагин я пробовал EnableCollectionSynchronization, но мне не помогало. Ну ок, помогло так помогло.